# create rails nested object in one swoop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need an api key to save a user, and I need a user_id to save an api_key... Can I do both at once?

```
user.api_key = ApkiKey.generate_token
user.save
user.api_key.user_id = user.id
user.api_key.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
#api_key.rb
before_create :generate_access_token
def generate_access_token
    begin
        self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
end

#user.rb
before_create do |user|
    user.api_key = ApiKey.create(user_id: user.id)
end
```

The problem was that I didn't think I could access user.id before I created the user, but apparently it works. Thanks for the heads up @Hardik

Answer (score 2):

If the `api_key` has `belongs_to` relationship with `user` then following will work

```
user.api_key = ApkiKey.generate_token
user.api_key.user_id = user.id
user.save
```

the `user.save` will also trigger the `user.api_key.save`